# How to browse $ Formations = $ em-> getRepository symfony2?

Tags: symfony, controller

How to browse

```
$formations = $em->getRepository ('.......')->findAll();
```

One by one to modify each var according to my need ??

Comment: Are you looking for a foreach loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know `php` you should train yourself before trying to learn a framework.

```
$formations = $em->getRepository (Formation::class)->findAll();
foreach($formations as $formation) {
   $formation->setTitle('My Modified Title')
}
```